# React router link keeps pushing to history same url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router 4. One concern I have is that if you use the `<Link />` component to navigate between routes, lets say in your header, and you click on that same link again it will keep pushing the same url to browser history? Is there any way to prevent this behaviour, or is it completely up to me as developer to either replace that `<Link />` with something something like a `<span>` element (if I dont want users to be able to click that link)?
Or should I do my own version of the `<Link />` component and then inside that prevent from firing events when on the same route?

Comment: The best way is , as you say, put a `<span>` or something don't clickable on the active link to prevent clicking

Comment: @MaximeGirou ok, cool!

Comment: @RakeshJakhar I think the question is enough to describe the concept I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, agree with @MaximeGirou. You can use your own trick.

Or another way is to define a class with some CSS properties [like cursor:not-allowed etc.] and give that class name in `activeClassName` attribute.

```
<NavLink to="/dashboard" activeClassName="linkActive">
   <i className="icon icon-home" /> <span>Dashboard</span>
</NavLink>
```

Comment: yes, thats true. I guess you mean the ```<Navlink />``` component, and maybe using css property for active class ```pointer-events: none;```

Comment: Yes, you got my point. I also use `NavLink`, but you asked for `Link` that's why I edited it.

Comment: Ah, didnt actually know ```<Link />``` was supporting ```activeClassName``` thats what I thought the ```<NavLink/>``` component was for. So what's the difference between those two components then?

Comment: My fault, you are right. The `activeClassName` is only supported by `Navlink`.